# EDIT: Ajax calls the wrong url

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, url

I am trying to transmit a value over my url call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/ajax/messages.html?lastClientMessage=" + lastClientMessage,
    success : function(messages) {},
    error : function() {},
    cache : false
});
```

My server gets the following message for example:

> /ajax/messages.html?lastClientMessage=1389288516000&_=1389289532718

I dont know what the "&_=" means. I think this url is the reason why my Controller can't handle the request. My Controller looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping("/ajax/messages.html")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Message> messages(@RequestParam(required = false) Long lastClientMessage) {}
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thank you for your first suggestions. I tried a few things and my Controller is getting the right variable now, but the return value isn't reaching my ajax function. Everytime the error part gets called. Am I doing something wrong? The List variable is correct.

Comment: "&_=" is added because you specified `cache : false`. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. In other words timestamp is added to avoid requested page caching. If you think that this parameter can cause an issue, then just remove it and check if it is indeed the problem.

Comment: Could you try sample url in browser and check what will be the result? For example: /ajax/messages.html?lastClientMessage=1389288516000

Comment: Also FYI, the value of the parameter "_" is equal to `new Date().getTime()` in javascript. And remember you cannot ensure caching to be disabled just by adding `cache: false`, you need to ensure the response headers for cache are set appropriately which may be done using a filter. See this link for more info. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in your variable *lastClientMessage*, use:

```
alert(lastClientMessage); 
$.ajax({
...
```

It must print exactly "1389288516000&_=1389289532718", so the problem is when you fill this variable.

Comment: In question it is already specified that server gets exactly these parameters.

Comment: the variable lastClientMessage isn't my problem.